# Quartz.Net JobListener events not fired

Tags: c#, wpf, quartz.net

I wrote a `JobListener` to keep track of Quartz jobs launched by a WPF app.

The app creates a list of jobs, calls a `BackgroundWorker` that schedules all the jobs and registers the `JobListener` for each one of them. The `JobListener` is intended to update different lists that will be dynamically displayed in the app user interface.

The jobs are scheduled and executed correctly, but for some unknown reason, the `JobListener` events are never fired.

**JobListener:**

```
class DummyJobListener : IJobListener
{
    private ObservableCollection<JobKey> _pendingJobs;
    private ObservableCollection<JobKey> _runningJobs;
    private ObservableCollection<JobKey> _finishedJobs;

    public readonly Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();

    public StressJobListener(ObservableCollection<JobKey> pendingJobs, ObservableCollection<JobKey> runningJobs, ObservableCollection<JobKey> finishedJobs)
    {
        _pendingJobs = pendingJobs;
        _runningJobs = runningJobs;
        _finishedJobs = finishedJobs;
    }

    public void JobToBeExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        JobKey jobKey = context.JobDetail.Key;
        _pendingJobs.Remove(jobKey);
        _runningJobs.Add(jobKey);
    }

    public void JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException)
    {
        JobKey jobKey = context.JobDetail.Key;
        _runningJobs.Remove(jobKey);
        _finishedJobs.Add(jobKey);
    }

    public void JobExecutionVetoed(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return "DummyJobListener" + Id; }
    }
}
```

**App :**

```
private BackgroundWorker _runJobs = new BackgroundWorker();

ObservableCollection<IJobDetail> jobList = new ObservableCollection<IJobDetail>();

ObservableCollection<JobKey> _pendingJobs = new ObservableCollection<JobKey>();
ObservableCollection<JobKey> _runningJobs = new ObservableCollection<JobKey>();
ObservableCollection<JobKey> _finishedJobs = new ObservableCollection<JobKey>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // fill jobList with jobs

    _runJobs.DoWork += RunJobs;
}


private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _runJobs.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void RunJobs(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    IScheduler scheduler = // GetScheduler

    foreach (IJobDetail x in jobList)
    {
        scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(new DummyJobListener(_pendingJobs, _runningJobs, _finishedJobs), KeyMatcher<JobKey>.KeyEquals(x.Key));
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(x, someTrigger);
        _pendingJobs.Add(x.Key);
    }

    scheduler.Start();

}
```

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

I missed the `quartz.threadPool.type` key in the configuration, which was set on `Quartz.Simpl.ZeroSizeThreadPool, Quartz` (this Quartz config is mainly used in a web environment). This setting is used when your scheduler only wants to schedule the jobs and not run them, leaving this task up to the Quartz Server running as a service. The "jobs getting executed with a non started scheduler" part should have lead me in this direction.

Changing this key to `Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz` solved the problem.

Comment: I had this config but in my case it still didn't work. I changed AddJobListener to AddGlobalJobListener and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running **scheduler.Start()**? I think the scheduler is disabled by default and you need to explicitly start it.

Comment: I didn't, but it still executed my jobs... Now I do (I edited the question), but the problem remains.

Comment: Have you tried adding the joblistener after you schedule the job? i.e. reversing the order of the two operations in your code.

Comment: The Quartz documentation suggests the following for adding a job listener...scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(myJobListener, KeyMatcher<JobKey>.KeyEquals(new JobKey("myJobName", "myJobGroup")));
Have you tried creating a new key in that way when adding the listener? I really can't see any other difference in your code to the documentation...

Comment: The key I use (the one stored in the job) is generated exactly this way. I never used JobListeners until today, that's why my code looks like the documentation one :) And that's why I don't understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: Did you try generating a new key like the code snippet I posted? I am not sure how the KeyMatcher class works under the hood but might make a difference.

Comment: I don't see how it could make a difference, because no matter if you create a key using new or pass an existing key, all that is received by the KeyMatcher is a JobKey reference (it's not aware whether you just created it or not). But I tried out of despair :) with the same result. ([Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/matchers/KeyMatcher.java?av=f) is how KeyMatcher works under the hood, at least in java).

Comment: No probs. I wouldn't have been able to rest without trying it. Sorry I couldn't help you!